# Can you get pinned in the 30 Years of WrestleMania?

Tags: wwe-2k14, wwe-2k-series

In WWE2K14, it states the opponent's damage but not yours. Can you get pinned or submit (lose) a match in the "2K Showcase" 30 Years of WrestleMania?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't take damage per-say, but you become easier to get pinned etc.